# Trouble Looping Through an Excel Table by Column First, then Row

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have an Excel table (365) imported from pdf data that I wish to write out specific Lot details for use elsewhere. I have all the code to do so and it nearly performs as expected!, but I am moving through the table row by row, and I really need the code to move through the table column by column - it affects the usability of the written output.
All of the output by column headers should be together...
Note: I'm only looking at the data - not writing into the Table. I think this is only a sequencing of code issue - but I'm stumped. I've read everything I can get my hands on about looping in tables, but I can't seem to make this work.
Any help would be gratefully received...

The guts of the code is here (full code attached)..

```vb
    For Each cell In tblDBR
    Select Case cell.Column
    Case 3 To 13        
        If cell.Value <> 0 Then
            Process each formatted item and move to next formatted cell etc
        End If
    End Select
    Next cell
```

This code moves through the table row by row (horizontally), and I need it to move (and therefore output) column by column (vertically).

Full code here...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'Macro to loop through LTD table and write 'lot' information for use elsewhere
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, tblCol As ListColumn, cell As Range, tblCols As ListColumns, tblDataCol As Range, tblDBR As Range, POD As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("LTD")
    Set tblDBR = tbl.DataBodyRange
    Set tblCols = tbl.ListColumns
    Set tblDataCol = tbl.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange
    POD = "CHINA"

    Range("N6").Select      'location to start writing Lots - arbitrary
 
    For Each cell In tblDBR
 
    Select Case cell.Column
    Case 3 To 13        'always this many columns, always starts at 3
    
    If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6        'useful color changer to show progress and problem
        ActiveCell.Value = tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, cell.Column - tbl.Range.Column + 1).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = "Lot " & cell.Offset(0, -(cell.Column - 1)).Value    'Lot Number
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -(cell.Column - 2)).Value & " M"      'Length
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(cell.Value, 0)   'Volume
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = POD      'Disport
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, -1).Select  'move down a line and start again
    End If
    End Select
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Snapshot of issue:
[image]

Comment: `Dim col As Range: For each col In tblDBR.Columns`

Comment: this would be easier using a Do Loop or For Loop that doesn't use a "for each". sure, you'd need to do a nested loop, but I believe in you.

Comment: Tim, Yoav24 .. many thanks. Only took me about 6 hours to nut this one but I got it.. thanks in part to you both putting an idea in my head.

Comment: I used this... importantly in this order!
For j = 3 To 13
For i = 1 To tblDBR.Rows.Count
For Each col In tblDBR.Columns